# Node + Express use NodeMailer appwide

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am trying to setup NodeMailer on my existing application. I am trying to setup the NodeMailer configuration on my main `app.ts`, then use it app wide to send mails wherever needed. This is what I have in my `app.ts`:

```
import * as mailer from 'nodemailer';

const app = express();
dotenv.load({ path: '.env' });
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

let mongodbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;    
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const mongodb = mongoose.connect(mongodbURI, { useMongoClient: true });

var mailConfig = {
  host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
  port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
  }
};
let transporter = mailer.createTransport(mailConfig);

mongodb
  .then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB on', db.host + ':' + db.port);    
    setRoutes(app);    
    if (!module.parent) {
      app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
        console.log('API listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
      });
    }    
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });

export { app };
```

I tried things like `app.use(transporter)` and `app.set('transporter',transporter)`. But seems that not quite the way to do it. How can I declare it app wide and use the object at other places like the `controller/user.ts`?

Comment: export it from app.ts and import it in your controller.

Comment: @vibhor1997a yes I am not sure how to do it. Can you please explain?

Comment: I'm not so sure about import export syntax as I use the old require and module.exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate js file for your transport and import it inside whichever module it is required.

transport.js

```
var mailer = require('nodemailer');
var mailConfig = {
  host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
  port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
  }
};

var transporter = mailer.createTransport(mailConfig);

module.exports = transporter;
```

app.js or any other module where you want to use nodemailer

```
var transporter = require('./transport');

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
        //Error
    } else {
        //Success
    }
});
```